# Difference of int to int[]

Tags: java, arrays, int

What is the difference of `int` to `int[]`. Is it allowed to convert `int` to `int[]`.

for example:

```
int[] a = {};
int b;
```

how can I pass the value of b to a?

Comment: It's the same difference between an apple and a crate built to store apples (and which may or may not be empty).

Answer (score 2):

You can't, that is an empty array, and arrays have fixed size (they receive their size at creation).

A possible way would be:

```
int b = 6;
int[] a = {b};
```

But this is equal to:

```
int[] a = new int[1];
int b = 6;
a[0] = b;
```

And that doesn't really make sense, as it stores only one element, so you might probably want to use collections, as they are variable length - like a `List`:

```
List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int b = 6;
a.add(b);
```

As for your initial question, an `int` stores an integer number (non-decimal), while an `int[]` stores a fixed number of `int`s.

Comment: Adding collections to your answer may confuse the OP as you will have to introduce Integer objects rather than primitives.

Comment: @JamesB It just felt like he was trying to make an empty list then append to it like you would in a scripting language, hence my addition of collection.

Comment: I know where you are coming from. Just saying that you may overload your answer with more information than the OP requires.

Answer (score 0):

`int []` is array of numbers of type `int` that **Just accept type int an not anything else**

you can see an array like which just accept type int  [image]

```
  1. when you define the length, you cannot change it after that
  2. when you define the type, it will just accept that type not anything else
  3. There are boundaries as you see in the picture so you can go beyond boundaries.
```

`int` is primitive type and you can see it like [image]

how to pass the `int` to `int[]`, you can

Code:

```
    int a =9;
    int[] b = {a};
```